# SQL-like functionality in R

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I am used to writing data manipulation logic in SQL and now that I am learning R I find myself sometimes just wanting to do something that would be simple in SQL but I have to learn a bunch of stuff with R to do the same manipulation on an R data frame. Is there a simple work around?

Comment: Can you give any examples please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

look at the package sqldf. http://code.google.com/p/sqldf/ It seems perfect for your needs.

Answer (score 11):

I'm also more comfortable with SQL, but when working with large data sets in R, my favourite manipulation tool is the `data.table` package. Unlike `sqldf`, which lets you write SQL in R, `data.table` lets you write R in R - but gives you the ability to add indexes on data frames (well, `data.table`s, to be precise). The ability to index data frames makes 'joins' much much much faster. And being an R implementation, your code still looks like R.